# Issue with an Autohotkey Script running in Windows 10

Tags: autohotkey

The following script doesn't work properly in Windows 10. The force shutdown screen doesn't go away (which is supposed to happen so the script can continue). I tried using ESC instead of ENTER along with adding two TABs before the ENTER (neither of those methods worked). I am using it to backup the RAM Disk (made with the driver I mentioned in my previous question) before shutting down/rebooting the OS:

```
#NoEnv
#Persistent
SendMode Input
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
SetTimer, RunBeforeShutdown, Off

Gui,+LastFound
hwnd:=WinExist()
DllCall("ShutdownBlockReasonCreate","Uint",hwnd,"Str","")
DllCall("kernel32.dll\SetProcessShutdownParameters", UInt, 0x4FF, UInt, 0)
;puts us first in line for getting the shutdown call, i guess?
OnMessage(0x11, "WM_QUERYENDSESSION")
Return

WM_QUERYENDSESSION(wParam, lParam)
{
    ENDSESSION_Logoff = 2147483648
    If (lParam == ENDSESSION_Logoff) {
        global EventType = "Logoff"
    } Else {
        global EventType = "Shutdown"
        ;no way to distinguish between shutdown and restart
    }

    SetTimer, RunBeforeShutdown, On
    Return false
}

runBeforeShutdown:
    SetTimer, RunBeforeShutdown, Off
    Sleep, 1000
    SendInput, {ENTER}  ; gets us past the 'Force shudown' screen
    Sleep, 1000
    #SingleInstance, Force
    DllCall("ShutdownBlockReasonDestroy","Uint",hwnd)
    ; **** Your commands go here ****
    RunWait cmd.exe /c backup.bat
    ; ********

    If (EventType == "Logoff") {
        Shutdown, 0
    } Else {
        Shutdown, 1
    }
    Reload
Return
```

EDIT: I ended up making a Scheduled Task that runs Drive Snapshot every night with parameters to back up the drive to a drive image.

Comment: Maybe rewrite your program to make use of [`OnExit`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnExit.htm) instead.

Comment: I would also encourage you to add the list of steps you want this code to do as they are unclear.

Comment: I want it to stop the shutdown/reboot process initiated by the Start Menu/Windows Update/etc., run the batch/program and then continue the shutdown/reboot process. That or delay the shutdown/reboot process until the program/batch has finished.